# SSH: "Permission denied" after changing user shell

Tags: shell, ssh, git

I have an SSH server running on my Raspberry PI with ALARM (up to date).
My user "gitroot" is meant to use the git-shell. However, when I set `/usr/bin/git-shell` as shell for gitroot in `/etc/passwd`, I can't login with that user anymore. `su - gitroot` works as expected. When I change the shell to `/bin/bash`, I can login as gitroot via ssh.

The permissions of `/usr/bin/git-shell` and `/bin/bash` are the same. I tried changing the password, it didn't change anything. Output from `journalctl -f`:

```
Jul 23 09:05:27 netberry sshd[4213]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure;logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost.localdomai...r=gitroot
Jul 23 09:05:40 netberry sshd[4213]: Failed password for gitroot from 127.0.0.1 port 51969 ssh2
Jul 23 09:07:25 netberry sshd[4213]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
Jul 23 09:07:29 netberry sshd[4222]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost.localdomai...r=gitroot
Jul 23 09:07:43 netberry sshd[4222]: Failed password for gitroot from 127.0.0.1 port 51970 ssh2
Jul 23 09:08:07 netberry sshd[4222]: Failed password for gitroot from 127.0.0.1 port 51970 ssh2
Jul 23 09:08:08 netberry sshd[4222]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost.localdomai...r=gitroot
Jul 23 09:08:10 netberry sshd[4222]: Failed password for gitroot from 127.0.0.1 port 51970 ssh2
Jul 23 09:08:10 netberry sshd[4222]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

The log shows multiple attempts to log in as gitroot over ssh from the host itself (I just typed `ssh gitroot@localhost` into the console).

Comment: Did you add `/usr/bin/git-shell` to `/etc/shells` if at all necessary?

Comment: Noo, i didnt. After i did, it worked. Thank you! If you want to post an answer with that, i will accept it because it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should add `/usr/bin/git-shell` to `/etc/shells`.